# Threepart Table with several panels

Tags: formatting, rotating, stata

I have an issue with my `threeparttable`s receiving input from Stata. I used to work earlier and it worked perfectly. But I twisted my tables a little and it throws error.

I want to have a table with panels. Each panel has two sub-columns and each subcolumn has four sub-sub columns. So in total, I have 9 columns one of which is the variable name and the rest are model names. The code is provided below:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp!]
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\small
\caption{Generalized DD Models}\label{Tab: Results1} 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccccccc@{}}
    \toprule\toprule
    
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{9}{c}{Panel A - Without Controls} \addlinespace 
    \cmidrule{2-9}
     
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Simple DD} &
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{PSM + DD} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    \cmidrule{6-9}
    \input{tabfig_MP/model1_5_dd_am12.tex}
    
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{9}{c}{Panel B - With Controls} \addlinespace 
    \cmidrule{2-9}
     
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Simple DD} &
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{PSM + DD} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    \cmidrule{6-9}
    \input{tabfig_MP/model1_6_dd_am12.tex} \\ \hline 

    \hline\hline
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \footnotesize
    \item \textit{Notes:}[1] Values in the brackets represent the standard errors. Standard errors is clustered at the school level. */**/*** denotes significance at the 10/5/1 percent.
    
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

In the above code `\input{tabfig_MP/model1_5_dd_am12.tex}` and `\input{tabfig_MP/model1_6_dd_am12.tex}` are input files from Stata. They are literally the same except for the coefficients. Below, I provide one of those input files:

```
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}     &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}   &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}   \\
&  Test Score   &Passing Rate   &Top University   &Participation Rate   &  Test Score   &Passing Rate   &Top University   &Participation Rate   \\
\hline
Treated                       &       -5.74   &       -0.34   &       -0.09   &       -4.63   &      -18.88   &       -5.62   &       -3.04   &       -5.31 \\
&      (7.53)   &      (2.66)   &      (1.16)   &      (4.78)   &     (12.10)   &      (4.15)   &      (1.93)   &      (6.98)   \\
Post                          &       55.99***&       18.53***&        2.10***&       28.91***&       57.74***&       18.50***&        1.10   &       31.72***\\
&      (3.72)   &      (1.28)   &      (0.57)   &      (2.52)   &     (10.57)   &      (3.71)   &      (1.64)   &      (5.17)   \\
Treated X Post                &       41.54***&       13.88***&        6.04***&       12.39** &       39.40***&       14.32***&        7.27***&        8.09   \\
&      (9.20)   &      (3.33)   &      (1.65)   &      (5.36)   &     (14.47)   &      (5.12)   &      (2.47)   &      (6.96)   \\
Boys School                   &       35.74***&        9.46***&        2.69***&       27.22***&       28.66***&        8.06** &        2.36   &       25.36***\\
&      (4.60)   &      (1.61)   &      (0.93)   &      (3.64)   &      (9.61)   &      (3.31)   &      (1.70)   &      (6.14)   \\
Treated X Post X Boys school  &      -16.32*  &       -4.59   &        1.00   &       -4.93   &       -9.70   &       -3.57   &        1.41   &       -3.89 \\
&      (9.55)   &      (3.71)   &      (2.38)   &      (8.02)   &     (13.15)   &      (4.97)   &      (2.85)   &      (9.50)   \\
Girls School                  &       -0.62   &       -5.35***&       -3.08***&        1.75   &        2.44   &       -7.05*  &       -5.67***&        3.58   \\
&      (4.96)   &      (1.69)   &      (0.72)   &      (3.49)   &     (13.46)   &      (4.25)   &      (1.70)   &      (6.56)   \\
Treated X Post X Girls School &      -48.05***&      -14.79***&       -6.01***&      -21.05** &      -50.81** &      -13.06*  &       -3.47   &      -22.11** \\
&     (17.17)   &      (5.69)   &      (2.16)   &      (9.29)   &     (21.54)   &      (6.95)   &      (2.67)   &     (11.01)   \\
Constant                      &       76.84***&       25.10***&        8.16***&       19.35***&       90.08***&       29.93***&       10.93***&       20.76***\\
&      (4.14)   &      (1.40)   &      (0.63)   &      (3.14)   &     (11.16)   &      (3.73)   &      (1.58)   &      (6.10)   \\
\hline
R-squared                     &        0.27   &        0.26   &        0.10   &        0.16   &        0.32   &        0.31   &        0.15   &        0.22 \\
Total Obs                     &        1158   &        1158   &        1158   &        1052   &         421   &         421   &         421   &         401 \\
```

When I run my main file that contains the libraries and necessary packages, it says `extra alignment tab has been changed to cr.`. I am sure the problem is not with my input files as it works with other contexts. I would appreciate it if anyone could help to figure out this.

Comment: Please extend your table fragment to complete small document.

Comment: Your table has a number of severe issues. To fix the `extra alignment tab has been changed to cr` error, you must change both instances of `\multicolumn{9}` to `\multicolumn{8}`; you must also supply line breaks in those lines. Even with just one external file loaded, the table pretty much fills up the entire page; I see no way to make both panels fit on a single page. You also have to allow line breaks inside the header cells of the 8 data columns in order to get the table's width not to exceed `\textwidth`.

Comment: Off-topic: The `[htbp!]` location specifier has *absolutely no effect* on the placement of a `sidewaystable`. Omit the location specifier, if only to reduce code clutter a wee bit.

Answer (score 1):

Beside considering @Mico comments (which solve your problem) I would use `S` columns and write column headers using `makecell` command defined in the package of the same name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\small
\caption{Generalized DD Models}
\label{Tab: Results1}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l 
                                *{8}{S[table-format=-2.2,
                                       table-space-text-post={$^{***})},
                                       input-symbols={( )}] }}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
    \multicolumn{8}{c}{Panel A - Without Controls} \\
    \addlinespace
    \cmidrule{2-9}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Simple DD} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PSM + DD} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    \cmidrule{6-9}
    %\input{tabfig_MP/model1_5_dd_am12.tex}
    &   \multicolumn{8}{c}{Panel B - With Controls} \\
%    \addlinespace
    \cmidrule{2-9}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Simple DD} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PSM + DD} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
    \cmidrule{6-9}
    %\input{tabfig_MP/model1_6_dd_am12.tex} \\ \hline
    &   {\makecell{(1)\\Test\\ Score}}  
    &   {\makecell{(2)\\Passing\\ Rate}}   
    &   {\makecell{(3)\\Top\\ University}}   
    &   {\makecell{(4)\\Participation\\ Rate}}   
    &   {\makecell{(5)\\Test\\ Score}}   
    &   {\makecell{(6)\\Passing\\ Rate}}  
    &   {\makecell{(7)\\Top\\ University}}   
    &   {\makecell{(8)\\Participation\\ Rate}}  \\
   \midrule
Treated     &   -5.74   &   -0.34   &   -0.09   &   -4.63   
            &   -18.88  &  -5.62    &   -3.04   &   -5.31   \\
            &   (7.53)  &   (2.66)  &   (1.16)  &   (4.78)  
            &   (12.10) &   (4.15)  &   (1.93)  &   (6.98)  \\
Treated X Post                
    & 41.54\tnote{***}  & 13.88\tnote{***}  & 6.04\tnote{***}   & 12.39\tnote{**}
    & 39.40\tnote{***}  & 14.32\tnote{***}  & 7.27\tnote{***}   &  8.09     \\
    &      (9.20)       &      (3.33)       &      (1.65)       & (5.36)   
    &     (14.47)       &      (5.12)       &      (2.47)       & (6.96)   \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
    \footnotesize
    \item \textit{Notes:}[1] Values in the brackets represent the standard errors. Standard errors is clustered at the school level. */**/*** denotes significance at the 10/5/1 percent.

\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zarko. The answer seems to work. I tried to use your code but it seemed that I needed to update my Latex editor. I uninstalled and installed it again. Now I face even terrible issues. My file does not run even without the troublesome tables. It throughs an error "! No room for a new \count ." I tried the web for potential solutions but I am getting none.

Comment: @Ahmad, why you should update editor? If you have old LaTeX installation, than you need to upgrade it. Which distribution of it you use? If MikTeX, than you can do this by help of MikTeX console (key Check updates).

Comment: I did not realize that at that time. Yes, I use MikTex. I uninstalled both and reinstalled them. Now it throughs several errors. I am afraid if there is compatibility issues and if I have to set up my document from scratch by debugging them one by one. I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: @Ahmad, sorry but I don't know what you doing. How you reinstall MikTeX? First try to remove it from your computer, than download MikTeX installer and install it. At this select "Always install missing packages on-the-fly.After completed installation for test try to compile MWE from ma Answer. It should be com piled "out-of-box".

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. Your manual solution is helpful. But the issue is that I have several input files and my regressions frequently change. So I have two files: one is my main paper document file and the second file is an intermediary file. The intermediary file is where I call the regression files and format tables. I use esttab to output regression tables. Can someone tell me how I can instruct esttab to output only the main body as you have shown?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's very similar to [@Zarko's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563821/5001), with the following main difference: Since you don't use any `\tnote` directives, using a `tablenotes` environment isn't necessary. In short, the `threeparttable` wrapper is omitted since it doesn't do anything useful.

This solution also incorporates the comments I posted earlier.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,makecell,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-space-text-post = ***,
         table-align-text-post = false,
         input-symbols={()} }
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\small
\caption{Generalized DD Models\strut}
\label{Tab:Results1} 

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
   l *{8}{S[table-format=-2.2]} }
\toprule
    
%    & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Panel A --- Without Controls}\\ 
%    \cmidrule{2-9}     
%    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Simple DD} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PSM + DD} \\
%    \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}
%    %\input{tabfig_MP/model1_5_dd_am12.tex}
%    \\

& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Panel B --- With Controls}\\
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Simple DD} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PSM + DD} \\
\cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}
%\input{tabfig_MP/model1_6_dd_am12.tex} \\ 
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} 
& {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} \\
& {\makecell{Test\\ Score}} & {\makecell{Passing\\ Rate}}
& {\makecell{Top\\University}} & {\makecell{Participation\\Rate}}   
& {\makecell{Test\\ Score}} & {\makecell{Passing\\ Rate}}
& {\makecell{Top\\University}} & {\makecell{Participation\\Rate}}
\\
\midrule
Treated        &  -5.74   &  -0.34   &  -0.09   &  -4.63   & -18.88   &  -5.62   &  -3.04   &  -5.31  \\
               & (7.53)   & (2.66)   & (1.16)   & (4.78)   & (12.10)  & (4.15)   & (1.93)   & (6.98)  \\
Post           &  55.99***&  18.53***&   2.10***&  28.91***&  57.74***&  18.50***&   1.10   & 31.72***\\
               & (3.72)   & (1.28)   & (0.57)   & (2.52)   &(10.57)   & (3.71)   & (1.64)   & (5.17)  \\
Treated $\times$ Post &  41.54***&  13.88***&   6.04***&  12.39** &  39.40***&  14.32***&   7.27***&  8.09   \\
               & (9.20)   & (3.33)   & (1.65)   & (5.36)   &(14.47)   & (5.12)   & (2.47)   & (6.96)  \\
Boys School    &  35.74***&   9.46***&   2.69***&  27.22***&  28.66***&   8.06** &   2.36   & 25.36***\\
               & (4.60)   & (1.61)   & (0.93)   & (3.64)   & (9.61)   & (3.31)   & (1.70)   & (6.14)  \\
Treated $\times$ Post $\times$ Boys school  & -16.32*  &  -4.59   &   1.00   &  -4.93   &  -9.70   &  -3.57   &   1.41   &  -3.89 \\
               & (9.55)   & (3.71)   & (2.38)   & (8.02)   &(13.15)   & (4.97)   & (2.85)   & (9.50)   \\
Girls School   &  -0.62   &  -5.35***&  -3.08***&   1.75   &   2.44   &  -7.05*  &  -5.67***&   3.58   \\
               & (4.96)   & (1.69)   & (0.72)   & (3.49)   &(13.46)   & (4.25)   & (1.70)   & (6.56)   \\
Treated $\times$ Post $\times$ Girls School & -48.05***& -14.79***&  -6.01***& -21.05** & -50.81** & -13.06*  &  -3.47   & -22.11** \\
               &(17.17)   & (5.69)   & (2.16)   & (9.29)   &(21.54)   & (6.95)   & (2.67)   &(11.01)   \\
Constant       &  76.84***&  25.10***&   8.16***&  19.35***&  90.08***&  29.93***&  10.93***&  20.76***\\
               & (4.14)   & (1.40)   & (0.63)   & (3.14)   &(11.16)   & (3.73)   & (1.58)   & (6.10)   \\
\midrule
R-squared      &   0.27   &   0.26   &   0.10   &   0.16   &   0.32   &   0.31   &   0.15   &   0.22   \\
Total Obs      & {1158}   & {1158}   & {1158}   & {1052}   & {421}    & {421}    & {421}    & {401}    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
\textit{Notes}: Values in parentheses represent standard errors. 
Standard errors are clustered at the school level. 
*/**/*** denote statistical significance at the 10/5/1 percent levels.

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answers were quite helpful. I a using esttab in stata to produce the regression file that you manually edited to answer my question. Since I have several regression tables and there frequent changes, I wonder if there is a way to instruct Stata to output only the part of the regression table below as per you edits.

```
Treated        &  -5.74   &  -0.34   &  -0.09   &  -4.63   & -18.88   &  -5.62   &  -3.04   &  -5.31  \\
               & (7.53)   & (2.66)   & (1.16)   & (4.78)   & (12.10)  & (4.15)   & (1.93)   & (6.98)  \\
Post           &  55.99***&  18.53***&   2.10***&  28.91***&  57.74***&  18.50***&   1.10   & 31.72***\\
               & (3.72)   & (1.28)   & (0.57)   & (2.52)   &(10.57)   & (3.71)   & (1.64)   & (5.17)  \\
Treated $\times$ Post &  41.54***&  13.88***&   6.04***&  12.39** &  39.40***&  14.32***&   7.27***&  8.09   \\
               & (9.20)   & (3.33)   & (1.65)   & (5.36)   &(14.47)   & (5.12)   & (2.47)   & (6.96)  \\
Boys School    &  35.74***&   9.46***&   2.69***&  27.22***&  28.66***&   8.06** &   2.36   & 25.36***\\
               & (4.60)   & (1.61)   & (0.93)   & (3.64)   & (9.61)   & (3.31)   & (1.70)   & (6.14)  \\
Treated $\times$ Post $\times$ Boys school  & -16.32*  &  -4.59   &   1.00   &  -4.93   &  -9.70   &  -3.57   &   1.41   &  -3.89 \\
               & (9.55)   & (3.71)   & (2.38)   & (8.02)   &(13.15)   & (4.97)   & (2.85)   & (9.50)   \\
Girls School   &  -0.62   &  -5.35***&  -3.08***&   1.75   &   2.44   &  -7.05*  &  -5.67***&   3.58   \\
               & (4.96)   & (1.69)   & (0.72)   & (3.49)   &(13.46)   & (4.25)   & (1.70)   & (6.56)   \\
Treated $\times$ Post $\times$ Girls School & -48.05***& -14.79***&  -6.01***& -21.05** & -50.81** & -13.06*  &  -3.47   & -22.11** \\
               &(17.17)   & (5.69)   & (2.16)   & (9.29)   &(21.54)   & (6.95)   & (2.67)   &(11.01)   \\
Constant       &  76.84***&  25.10***&   8.16***&  19.35***&  90.08***&  29.93***&  10.93***&  20.76***\\
               & (4.14)   & (1.40)   & (0.63)   & (3.14)   &(11.16)   & (3.73)   & (1.58)   & (6.10)   \\
\midrule
R-squared      &   0.27   &   0.26   &   0.10   &   0.16   &   0.32   &   0.31   &   0.15   &   0.22   \\
Total Obs      & {1158}   & {1158}   & {1158}   & {1052}   & {421}    & {421}    & {421}    & {401}    \\
```